# PSTricks environment with automatically aligned mathematical expression

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, pstricks

**Code**

Consider the following (more or less relevant) code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}

\fbox{\begin{pspicture}(10,10)
  \rput(5,5){\emph{Aligned} math expression on top of a PSTricks drawing}
\end{pspicture}}

\end{document}
```

**Question**

As indicated in the code, I would like to have an *aligned* math expression on top of a PSTricks drawing. Is this possible and if it is, how do I do it?

Comment: This  is quite vague. Could you post a sketch of what you'd like (and the code of the drawing, if possible)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to use horizontal math (`$...$`) rather than `align` or `\[...\]`, which are vertical-mode constructs.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}

\fbox{\begin{pspicture}(10,10)
  \rput(5,5){$\begin{aligned}
   y &= mx + b\\
   y_1 &= 3x^2 + 2x + 4
   \end{aligned}$}
\end{pspicture}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

p.s. The `tabstackengine` constructs are also horizontal and could be used here, as well.

Comment: Thank you very much, Steven!

Comment: You are most welcome, @SvendTveskæg